# Asian characters and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, asianfonts

I have unit tests which contains asians chars (chineses ideograms), but Eclipse just display them as a square. When I copy and paste ideograms from a web page I have the same problem.
My workspace is in UTF-8, my project and all it files too.

My collegue can copy and paste asians chars with Eclipse on his MacBook, but Eclipse on Windows does not allow this.

Is there a trick?

Thanks
Cédric Girard

ps: I use Helios, build 20100617-1415 on Windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be that your Windows installation is not supporting Asian characters yet. Check this: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_install_languages.mspx?mfr=true

If you're using SCM like SVN, check also that the configuration is correct. For SVN, check this: http://www.tigris.org/scdocs/SVNEncoding